# MAC Pair details with Conntrack Program

Tags: macintosh

As conntrack displays the IP pairs detail. Is it possible to fetch MAC pairs per flow? Just similar to ovs-dpctl dump-flow in ovs environment.

Comment: You should probably give us an example of "ovs-dpctl dump-flow ", and / or add explicitly what you are looking for the output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.